# Discretization : converting continuous values into a certain number of categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bin, discretization

```
1   Create a column Usage_Per_Year from Miles_Driven_Per_Year by discretizing the values into three equally sized categories. The names of the categories should be Low, Medium, and High.

2   Group by Usage_Per_Year and print the group sizes as well as the ranges of each.

3   Do the same as in #1, but instead of equally sized categories, create categories that have the same number of points per category.

4   Group by Usage_Per_Year and print the group sizes as well as the ranges of each.
```

My codes are below

```
df["Usage_Per_Year "], bins = pd.cut(df["Miles_Driven_Per_Year"], 3, precision=2, retbins=True)
group_label = pd.Series(["Low", "Medium", "High"])
#3.3.2
group_size = df.groupby("Usage_Per_Year").size()
#print(group_size)
print(group_size.reset_index().set_index(group_label))
#3.3.3
Year2 = pd.cut(df["Miles_Driven_Per_Year"], 3, precision=2)
group_label = pd.Series(["Low", "Medium", "High"])
#3.3.4
group_size = df.groupby("Usage_Per_Year").size()
#print(group_size)
print(group_size.reset_index().set_index(group_label))
```

the out put is below:

> ```
>                Usage_Per_Year     0 Low       (-1925.883, 663476.235]  6018 Medium  (663476.235, 1326888.118]     0 High     (1326888.118, 1990300.0]     1
>                Usage_Per_Year     0 Low       (-1925.883, 663476.235]  6018 Medium  (663476.235, 1326888.118]     0 High     (1326888.118, 1990300.0]     1
> ```

but -1925 is wrong...

The right answer should be like this.
[image]

How can I do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a typo on line 1: `df["Usage_Per_Year "]`? There is a space at the end of the column name.

`pd.cut` bins values into equal size. That's why all of your bins have same size. It seems that you should compute the min and max of each group *after* binning.

Also, to bin value into equal frequency, you should use `pd.qcut`.

---

Example input:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng(20210514)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Miles_Driven_Per_Year': rng.gamma(1.05, 10000, (1000,)).astype(int)
})

# 1
group_label = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High']
df['Usage_Per_Year'] = pd.cut(df['Miles_Driven_Per_Year'],
                              bins=3, labels=group_label)

# 2
print(df.groupby('Usage_Per_Year').agg(['count', 'min', 'max']))

# 3
df['Usage_Per_Year'] = pd.qcut(df['Miles_Driven_Per_Year'],
                               q=3, labels=group_label)

# 4
print(df.groupby('Usage_Per_Year').agg(['count', 'min', 'max']))
```

Example output:

```
               Miles_Driven_Per_Year              
                               count    min    max
Usage_Per_Year                                    
Low                              878     31  20905
Medium                           107  20955  41196
High                              15  41991  62668
               Miles_Driven_Per_Year              
                               count    min    max
Usage_Per_Year                                    
Low                              334     31   4378
Medium                           333   4449  11424
High                             333  11442  62668
```